# Can I force std::vector to leave a memory leak?

Tags: c++, swig

Can I force std::vector to not deallocate its memory after the vector goes out of scope?

For example, if I have

```cpp
int* foo() {
    std::vector<int> v(10,1); // trivial vector
    return &v[0];
}

int main()
{
    int* bar = foo();
    std::cout << bar[5] << std::endl;
}
```

There is no guarantee that the values will still be accessible here.

I am currently simply doing this

```cpp
int* foo() {
  std::vector<int> v(10,1);
  int* w = new int[10];
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    w[i] = v[i];
  }
  return w;
}
```

but it is a little wasteful to repopulate a whole new array. Is there a way to force std::vector to not delete its array?

Note: I am not returning the vector itself because I am interfacing c++ with python using SWIG, and `ARG_OUTVIEW_ARRAY` requires a raw pointer and, in fact, an intentional memory leak. I would still however like to be able to make use of vector features while constructing the data itself.

Comment: why does `foo` not return an `int` ? Eventually someone has to store the value...

Comment: The problem is that python code is going to be the eventual owner of the vector, and the conversion requires me to leave a 'memory leak' on purpose. I don't just return an int because I will need the entire array in python.

Comment: @TheZhengmeister: why not `std::vector<int> v = new std::vector<int>(10,1);` in `foo`?

Comment: Why not just use a raw array with SWIG? It is possible.

Comment: @P.W that works actually! I can then just take ```&(*v)[0]```, right?

Comment: @rustyx can you elaborate on how to do this? My issue is that I don't know the size of the array before the c++ code is run, so I can't pass an ```INPLACE_ARRAY``` and populate it during.

Comment: @TheZhengmeister No, this is a terrible idea. If you return `&(*v)[0]`, you'll leak the vector itself, even if you free its internal array.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ah yes of course, I shall avoid this.

Comment: Why don't you return the vector instead of a pointer to its data?

Comment: Do you want to do this because you don't know how to return a `std::vector<int>` properly?  The typemaps that support it come with SWIG, or use the `numpy` typemaps.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I am using the numpy.i interface ([documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/swig.interface-file.html)), but is there a way of getting it to work directly with ```std::vector```?

Comment: `%include <std_vector.i>` then `%template(IntVector) std::vector<int>;` will allow passing and return of vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `vector` is desiged to prevent leaks.

But if you want to shoot yourself in the foot, it's possible. Here's how you prevent the vector from deallocating its internal array:

```
int *foo()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10,1);

    int *ret = v.data();
    new (&v) std::vector<int>; // Replace `v` with an empty vector. Old storage is leaked.
    return ret;
}
```

As the other answers say, you should never do it.

Comment: This is much more easier and cleaner than using custom allocator. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's UB, but granted that should hopefully work on common runtimes...

Comment: @Quentin One could get UB when `delete[]`ing the pointer later, if for some reason `v[0]` is not at the beginning of the allocated storage. I think placement-new itself is well-defined here, since one is allowed to destroy objects by reusing their storage. Also, if `vector` manages some other resource in addition to a single block of heap memory, we leak that. Does that sound correct?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat deletion should use the exact same form that `std::vector` uses internally, allocators and all -- would probably match `delete[]` in the plain case, but is not guaranteed to. I'm unsure whether cutting the lifetime of a non-trivially-destructible object short through placement-new is well-defined.

Answer (score 9):

**It is possible but you should never do it. Forcing a vector to leave memory leak is a terrible idea and if you need such a thing then you need to re-think your design. std::vector is a resource managing type whose one of the main goals is to ensure that we don't have a leak. Never try to break that.**

Now, to answer your specific question: `std::vector` takes an allocator type as second template parameter which is default to `std::allocator<T>`. Now you can write a custom allocator that doesn't release any memory and use that with your vector. Writing a custom allocator is not very trivial work, so I'm not going to describe that here (but you can Google to find the tutorials).

If you really want to use custom allocator then you must ensure that your vector never triggers a grow operation. Cause during growing capacity the vector will move/copy data to new location and release the old memories using the allocator. If you use an allocator that leaks then during growing you not only retain the final data, but also retain the old memories which I'm sure that you don't want to retain. So make sure that you create the vector with full capacity.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Vectors are not implemented to have memory leaks, and the interface does not provide a way to create one.

You can't "steal" the memory (removing ownership of it from the vector), which *is* possibly a bit of a shame.

Sorry, but you are going to have to either copy (as you're doing now), or not use vector.

Comment: What about using a custom allocator that doesn't free memory? I know that it's a terrible idea but should be possible to implement.

Comment: I'm not going to entertain such hackery!

Comment: Lol. Yes, such hackery should be avoided but it is technically possible. At least may be just for fun :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea, but possible by creating a custom allocator that does not deallocate as said in other answers.

For example : (boilerplate mostly from [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator))

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct LeakingAllocator 
{
  using value_type = T;
  LeakingAllocator() = default;

  template <typename U> constexpr LeakingAllocator(const LeakingAllocator<U>&) noexcept {}

  T* allocate(std::size_t n) 
  {
    if(n > std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(T)) throw std::bad_alloc(); // check for overflow

    if(auto p = static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(n*sizeof(T)))) return p; // return p if malloc returns a valid object
    throw std::bad_alloc(); // otherwise just throw.
  }

  void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t) noexcept { /*leak intentionally*/ }
};


template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(const LeakingAllocator<T>&, const LeakingAllocator<U>&) { return true; }
template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator!=(const LeakingAllocator<T>&, const LeakingAllocator<U>&) { return false; }

template <typename T>
using LeakingVector = std::vector<T, LeakingAllocator<T>>;
```

Then code like

```
int* ret()
{
    LeakingVector<int> a;
    a.resize(10);
    return &a[0];
}

int main()
{
    auto ptr = ret();
    *ptr = 10;
    std::cout << *ptr;
}
```

becomes valid.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but, yes.

You can create a custum [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) who do nothing when deallocate => leak

Or may be you can jsut create your `vector`on the heap so it will leak anyway.

```
int* foo() {
    std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>(10,1); 
    return &((*v)[0]);
    // no delete
}

int main()
{
    int* bar = foo();
    std::cout << bar[5] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The second option would create an actual leak (rather than removing ownership of the buffer from `vector`, which is what OP seems to want).

Comment: This introduces far too much risk of accidentally leaking more than the desired amount of memory. Also, you don't have a strategy for eventually freeing the memory once you're done with it. This is a terrible idea.

Comment: Of course it's a terrible idea, but OP want to create a leak, I help him doing so ^^

Comment: The question title is misleading. OP seems to want to reuse a buffer form a vector, not leak it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right, I do need to reuse the vector's buffer, but outside of the scope of the c++ code (python will deal with it). So I'm also not sure if 'leak' is the right word.

Comment: @TheZhengmeister the example shown here will in addition to the array leak the `vector` object itself. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

And you're doing it wrong. <s>Return the vector instead so the lifetime works out:</s>

Write your own special Python memory vector `class`, something like (most crudely):

```
template <typename T>
class python_vector
{
    T* buffer_;
public:
    python_vector(size_t n, const T& value) : buffer_{new T(n)}
    {}
    // copy, assignment, operator[](), *etc*
    ~python_vector()
    {
        // DO NOTHING!
    }
}

python_vector<int> foo() {      
    python_vector<int> v(10,1);
    // process v
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    python_vector<int> bar = foo();  // copy allusion will build only one python_vector here
    std::cout << bar[5] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned why he does not return a vector in a note at the end of the question.

Comment: @P.W But he wants the `vector` data to outlive that return? Design is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: I need the data to outlive the return because SWIG needs a 'memory leak' so that python can take control of the memory and then deallocate it after the lifetime of the c++.

Comment: @TheZhengmeister Then `vector` is the wrong tool. Allocate and manage the memory in a way you can control so that it doesn't get freed in a C++ lifetime.

Comment: Whoever downvoted: so you think it's better coding practice to mutilate `vector` to do something it was never intended to rather then write some code to do it right?

Comment: Didn't downvote but maybe its because your `python_vector` is very incomplete? and by manually managing your own memory you open up another can of worms. (writing correct special member functions etc).

Comment: @SombreroChicken I said *most crudely*.  It's not in `vector`'s spec to have it's buffer stolen so you've already open your can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you would most probably write:

```
auto foo()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10,1); // trivial vector
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    const auto bar = foo();
    std::cout << bar[5] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I need a raw pointer because I am using SWIG to interface the c++ with python, which transfers the memory management to python after c++ goes out of scope. It needs to be a 'leak' because otherwise the OS might just overwrite the allocated memory.

Comment: I don't think, Python is able to correctly manage memory allocated by a C++ run-time. Perhaps you should obtain memory from Python and copy the vector data into it.