# Is it possible to use std::basic_string as a wrapper around char*?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stl

I have third party library that returns char* (and wchar_t*) that are created in it by strdup (and wcsdup functions respectively).

I want to avoid calling free manually at the end of my code.

Is it possible to write an allocator for std::basic_string so that it would handle dealing with this c-strings returned by this library? Ideally I don't want to allocate any new memory at all and use memory blocks that were returned (strings are supposed to be constant).

Comment: I'd say a smart ptr with a string_view but thats c++17 sadly.

Comment: @SombreroChicken that would only take care of the string_view, not the underlying char array. string_view is non-owning.

Comment: @Steve The smart pointer would take care of it. It's why I said both.

Comment: @SombreroChicken, yes, it'd take care of the string_view, not the underlying array.

Comment: @Steve obviously a smart ptr owning the returned `char*`. Not the string_view.

Comment: If we imagine this was possible, what happens if you `push_back` on the wrapping string?

Comment: Sort of the opposite of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56127946/560648 lol

Comment: What about providing an allocator for `std::basic_string`? I never done that, so I'm not sure how reasonable solution this could be.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, std::string does its own memory management and can't reuse a malloced string.

You could copy them to a std::string and immediately delete them, but that will invoke all the behaviours you are trying to avoid.

What you can do is immediately declare a unique_ptr with a custom deleter. When that goes out of scope, it will call the deleter, which will be `free()`. Meanwhile, you can use it in the same way you would have used the raw pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(free)*> RAII(makeAPICall(), free);
```

In the future you could create an owning wrapper for std::string_view, and perhaps there is advantage in rolling your own in the short term, but unless you have a newer stdlib (c++17) that has replicated all the methods to take string_view I recon it is an exercise in futility.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a functor! But I have been down that path... it is worth working through the syntax error for yourself.

Comment: Ah! My mistake! Corrected!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `std::basic_string`.  `std::basic_string` manages it's own memory so it would allocate new storage and copy the data into the string.  You would still have to manually release the storage from the returned pointer.

If you can use C++17 you could use a `std::basic_string_view` as it will just hold a copy of the pointer, but you run into the same issue where you would need to call the deallocation function manually for the pointer when you are done with it.

What you could do is use a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter to store the returned pointer from the function so it will automatically reallocate the memmory for you.  Then, if you can use C++17 you can get a `std::basic_string_view` to that pointer so you have all of the string functions without having to make a copy.  Otherwise would could just use the c-string function from `<cstring>` to work with it or write your own version of `std::basic_string_view` (or find a C++11 library that has one like [this one](https://github.com/martinmoene/string-view-lite))

Answer (score 3):

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) there is `string_view`.

```
template<class T, class Deleter=std::default_delete<T>>
struct string_view_buff : std::string_view<T> {
  std::unique_ptr<T[]> buff;
  explicit string_view_buff( T* in, Deleter d = {} ):
    buff( in, std::move(d) ),
    std::string_view<T>(in) {}
};
```

something like that can take ownership of a buffer and expose string-like functionality at the same time without additional heap allocation.  (Code not tested)

Prior to that, no, `std::string` allocates and manages its own memory.  You cannot give it a buffer and a deletion function.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to avoid calling free manually at the end of my code.

If the library doesn't do that, then there is no way for you to avoid calling `free` (disregarding intentionally leaking the memory).

If the library itself doesn't use the string, then if you wish to use `std::string` and `std::wstring`, you can use the constructor that accepts a `CharT*`, and immediately after creating the string, deallocate the original using `free`.

If you wish to avoid additional allocation and copying, then `std::string` is not an option. You can use a smart pointer to deallocate when the pointer goes out of scope.